# NSUserDefaults.addSuiteNamed() having no effect

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I created an app group to share preferences between an iOS app and an extension. From either app I can get a defaults instance and successfully read and write values like this:

```
let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.example")
sharedDefaults.setObject("bar", forKey: "foo")
sharedDefaults.stringForKey("foo") // → "bar"
```

However, adding the group’s suite name to standardUserDefaults has no effect:

```
let standardDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
standardDefaults.addSuiteNamed("group.com.example")
standardDefaults.stringForKey("foo") // → nil
```

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the remove Suite method at the end of your first three lines of code, and setup a breakpoint in this line in Xcode. See if your specified key value pairs get removed from the search list.

```
let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.example")
sharedDefaults.setObject("bar", forKey: "foo")
sharedDefaults.stringForKey("foo") // → "bar"
sharedDefaults.removeSuite(suiteName: "group.com.example")//remove suite
//put a breakpoint here.
```